# How do I transfer value of header from HttpTrigger to Http Action in a logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-workflow-automation

I have a logic app and I am trying to transfer the headers from a HttpTrigger to a Http operation, i.e. I am trying to forward the request

[image]

How can I get the request-signature value from my original request's header into the Http Operation?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a Parse json step in between. This can be used to extract the data elements from the header in your incoming request.

Set your "Contents" to Headers as shown. Then click on "Use sample payload" and paste your headers in JSON form. It will automatically create the schema for you. Then in any following steps you will be able to use the fields from your header.
[image]

[image]